Material UI React no me carga bien los estilos
estoy implementando MUI en un proyecto nuevo,  estaba haciendo una lista:

Pero , en cuanto a estilos... poco tiene que ver con esto :

He seguido las instalaciones como dice la docu, este es mi package.json :
{
  "name": "todo",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@emotion/react": "^11.11.4",
    "@emotion/styled": "^11.11.5",
    "@fontsource/roboto": "^5.0.12",
    "@mui/icons-material": "^5.15.15",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.17.0",
    "@testing-library/react": "^13.4.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^13.5.0",
    "normalize.css": "^8.0.1",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "react-scripts": "5.0.1",
    "uuid": "^9.0.1",
    "web-vitals": "^2.1.4"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  }
}

He probado a poner el app.js asi :
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom/client';
import App from './App';
import theme from './theme';
import CssBaseline from '@mui/material/CssBaseline';
import { ThemeProvider } from '@emotion/react';
import '@fontsource/roboto/300.css';
import '@fontsource/roboto/400.css';
import '@fontsource/roboto/500.css';
import '@fontsource/roboto/700.css';
const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root'));
root.render(

{/* CssBaseline kickstart an elegant, consistent, and simple baseline to build upon. */}


,
Antes lo tenia si el themeprovider ese pero lo puse para ver si cambiaba algo, pero tampoco, el theme que esta leyendo es este (un ejemplo que vi por ahi de la docu) :
import { red } from '@mui/material/colors';
import { createTheme } from '@mui/material/styles';

// A custom theme for this app
const theme = createTheme({
  palette: {
    primary: {
      main: '#556cd6',
    },
    secondary: {
      main: '#19857b',
    },
    error: {
      main: red.A400,
    },
  },
});

export default theme;

pero no creo que sea ese el problema, entiendo que esto al final deberia de ser como bootstrap, mediante clases ( en este caso componentes) te deberia de crear un componente medianamente bonito y con estilos preconfigurados, no una lista blanca no ?
La logica me funciona, el problema son los estilos.
